# In a batch file, how do you verify part of a filename matches a given string?

Tags: string, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a directory full of files that look like the following:

```
Codian1_OCT_14_2014_14_52_ccc145b1_WMV.asf
Codian1_OCT_14_2014_14_52_ccc145b1_ASF.asf
Codian1_OCT_13_2014_12_52_ccc145b1_WMV.asf
Codian1_OCT_13_2014_12_52_ccc145b1_ASF.asf
```

I'm trying to test if the file ends in either WMV.asf or ASF.asf. For some reason the following code doesn't work:

```
FOR %%i IN (*) DO (IF %%~i=="*WMV.asf" (echo %%~i IS wmv.asf) ELSE (echo %%~i isn't wmv.asf))
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comparisons should be case insensitive, since Windows doesn't care about case within file paths.

Option 1

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (*) do (
  set "file=%%i"
  if /i "!file:~-7!"=="wmv.asf" (echo %%i IS wmv.asf) else (echo %%i isn't wmv.asdf)
)
```

Option 2

```
for %%i in (*) do echo %%i|findstr /ile "wmv.asf" >nul && (echo %%i IS wmv.asf) || (echo %%i isn't wmv.asf)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%i IN (*) DO (
 set $File=%%i
 if /i !$File:~-7!==WMV.asf echo !$File! -^> WMV
 if /i !$File:~-7!==ASF.asf echo !$File! -^> ASF)
```